# Higher R2 by adding insignificant variables, how?

Tags: regression, correlation, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, r-squared

I got a quick question about the statistical analysis for my thesis.

**Background information.** I am running a multifactor risk model to asses returns for certain stocks and including market returns, technology firms' returns, and commodity prices (oil, natural gas and coal) as regressors.

However, I run into some trouble. The commodities natural gas and coal have been found to have no (significant) correlation with any of the other variables (nor dependent or independent). But running the multiple linear regression with these two variables (natural gas and coal) raises the $R^2$ very slightly (from 0.527 to 0.528), while the coefficients are insignificant.

Can anyone help explain to me how $R^2$ can rise even though both extra included variables are insignificant and do not have a correlation?

I am analysing with SPSS and Excel by the way.

Kind regards

Comment: There are a number of related threads, and yours is most likely a duplicate. You can find more detailed answers if you do a little search on Cross Validated.

Comment: I think the term "significant" is confusing you (as it has two meanings: P<alpha and big enough to matter). Put that term aside and think about what results mean. Why would you expect R2 to go up if p=0.049 and not if p=0.051?

Comment: @HarveyMotulsky For that matter, not every field even likes $0.05$ as the threshold for significance!

Answer (score 3):

$R^2$ will never decrease as the number of variables increases. This is because, for any finite sample, a small insignificant portion of the remaining variation (assuming $R^2$ is not already 1) can be explained by the added variable(s), even though the estimated coefficient is not statistically significant from 0. This is why we worry about overfitting a model when we base goodness of fit on $R^2$ alone.

Comment: I cannot understand your second sentence.

Comment: Sorry my second sentence was incomplete. I have edited it.

Comment: The first sentence is true if we minimize square loss. [If we estimate another way, all bets are off.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/598458/247274)

Answer (score 2):

Ordinary least-squares regression yields the values of the regression coefficients that maximize $R^2$. As more variables are introduced, $R^2$ will in general increase: the unconstrained model (with $\beta_{coal},\beta_{gas}\in\mathbb{R}$) can only have a maximum value of $R^2$ that is greater or equal to the maximum value of $R^2$ for the constrained model (with $\beta_{coal}=\beta_{gas}=0$), whether the effect is "significant" or not. Even if the association between the dependent variable and these regressors arose purely by chance (which may be the case if it is not statistically significant), ordinary least square regression will take advantage of this spurious association and maximize $R^2$ accordingly -- which is called overfitting. However, as more data are gathered, it is likely that the improvement of $R^2$ will fade away.

This, is why alternative metrics of goodness-of-fit (e.g. adjusted $R^2$) are sometimes preferred to $R^2$, which is spuriously inflated when there are relatively many predictors compared to the amount of data points. In order to avoid overfitting altogether, one may perform Regularized regression (e.g. Ridge regression) instead of Ordinary Least Square regression. Regularised regression will penalise values of the regression coefficients that strongly depart from 0, unless there is strong evidence for large values. This will reduce $R^2$, especially for small datasets. Alternatively, Bayesian regression can extract the probability distribution of $\beta_{coal}$ in light of the data. Arguably, this probability distribution conveys more information about the magnitude of the effect of coal prices than a comparison of $R^2$ (or its adjusted counterpart) with and without including the variable as a predictor. Besides, Bayesian regression naturally implements some form of regularisation.

Notwithstanding these general considerations about $R^2$ as a measure of goodness-of-it, an increase of $R^2$ from 0.527 to 0.528 is so small that it clearly suggests that the effect of these extra variables is not significant anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It just means your dependent variable is not significantly dependent upon those independent variables. Increasing or decreasing them won't have a significant impact. But they can still have a minor (insignificant) correlation to the dependent variable, which is why the $R^2$ went up just a bit. The minor insignificant correlation is nothing to conclude from and can be ignored.